# How to deserialize App Engine application logs from StackDriver Logging API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

As part of migrating to Python 3, I need to migrate from [logservice](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice) to the [StackDriver Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/api-overview). I have [google-cloud-logging](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-logging/) installed, and I can successfully fetch GAE application logs with eg:

```
>>> from google.cloud.logging_v2 import LoggingServiceV2Client
>>> entries = LoggingServiceV2Client().list_log_entries(('projects/projectname',),
         filter_='resource.type="gae_app" AND protoPayload.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog"')
>>> print(next(iter(entries)))
proto_payload {
  type_url: "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog"
  value: "\n\ts~brid-gy\022\0018\032R5d..."
}
```

This gets me a `LogEntry` with text application logs in the `proto_payload.value` field. How do I deserialize that field? I've found lots of related mentions in the docs, but nothing pointing me to a `google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog` protobuf generated class anywhere that I can use, if that's even the right idea. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`LogEntry.to_api_repr()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/entries.html#google.cloud.logging.entries.LogEntry.to_api_repr) function to get a JSON version of the `LogEntry`.

```
>>> from google.cloud.logging import Client
>>> entries = Client().list_entries(filter_="severity:DEBUG")        
>>> entry = next(iter(entries))
>>> entry.to_api_repr()
{'logName': 'projects/PROJECT_NAME/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions'
, 'resource': {'type': 'cloud_function', 'labels': {'region': 'us-central1', 'function_name': 'tes
t', 'project_id': 'PROJECT_NAME'}}, 'labels': {'execution_id': '1zqolde6afmx'}, 'insertI
d': '000000-f629ab40-aeca-4802-a678-d513e605608e', 'severity': 'DEBUG', 'timestamp': '2019-10-24T2
1:55:14.135056Z', 'trace': 'projects/PROJECT_NAME/traces/9c5201c3061d91c2b624abb950838b4
0', 'textPayload': 'Function execution started'}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! this doesn't work for me though. `to_api_repr()` gives me: `TypeError: Can not find message descriptor by type_url: type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog.` Looks like google cloud python library maintainers have struggled with this themselves for years now: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/2572 , https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/2674

Answer (score 4):

Woo! Finally got this working. I had to generate and use the Python bindings for the `google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog` protocol buffer myself, by hand. Here's how.

First, I cloned these two repos at head:

- https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis.git
- https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git

Then, I generated `request_log_pb2.py` from `request_log.proto` by running:

```sh
protoc -I googleapis/ -I protobuf/src/ --python_out . googleapis/google/appengine/logging/v1/request_log.proto
```

Finally, I pip installed `googleapis-common-protos` and `protobuf`. I was then able to deserialize `proto_payload` with:

```py
from google.cloud.logging_v2 import LoggingServiceV2Client
client = LoggingServiceV2Client(...)
log = next(iter(client.list_log_entries(('projects/brid-gy',),
   filter_='logName="projects/brid-gy/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log"')))

import request_log_pb2
pb = request_log_pb2.RequestLog.FromString(log.proto_payload.value)
print(pb)
```

Comment: For users stumped on where `request_log_pb2.py` ends up after running the `protoc` command, a whole dir structure is created: `google/appengine/logging/v1/request_log_pb2.py` .

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to use the API v2 ?

If not, use `from google.cloud import logging` and 
 set `os.environ['GOOGLE_CLOUD_DISABLE_GRPC'] = 'true'` - or similar env setting.

That will effectively return a JSON in `payload` instead of `payload_pb`